# Change UIView to another one in MainStoryboard

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have an a tab based app in which some parts are for everybody, but user should be registered to access, so, I want to change to a UIView to the Login one.

Login view is allocated in the first tab, in MainStoryboard

[image]

Now I'm in another tab, another section (which already has a .xib file) and I want to show the "Login" view:

```
 Login *aLogin = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"LOGIN" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:aLogin animated:YES];
```

But it crashes because of LOGIN xib doesnt exist.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
```

How can I load the "login" uiview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 Login *aLogin = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
 [self presentModalViewController:aLogin animated:YES];
```

Comment: I can't! As I wrote the answer I have to wait 2 days!